# Tool to migrate Access database to SQL CE

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-ce

Is there any free tool that can migrate Access Database to SQL CE

I currently have an Access database 2003 and want to import into SQL CE 3.5

Answer (score 0):

When you can do is upside your data from access to SQL (you can even use one of the free expression editions).  You then can script out the whole database, or pull the data from sql server into your version of SQL lite.

Comment: Albert, did you read the question? It's about SQL CE, not SQL Server or SQL Lite.